# Chrome OS Developer Options Root Password

Tags: uefi, root, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I'm trying to flash a custom UEFI system or BIOS to my Chromebook (Lenovo c330) and I ran the command in the Shell in Crosh and it asked me for my password. I entered the password for my Google account, and it said incorrect password. I tried what the other posts said and tried things like `password` or `12345678` or `1234567890` but none of them worked. I looked all over the internet and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Is this your own personal Chromebook, or does it belong to an organisation?

Comment: @Tetsujin This is my personal chromebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found help from someone online. The password was `Admin`. Apparently it's one of the main passwords that a shell would have. Thanks for trying to help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly there is no password. You need to set it up with:

```
sudo passwd root
```

this will allow you to set the root password

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).